# WSGI with SSL behind NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx, pyramid, wsgi, pylons

currently I want to deploy my pyramid application on a server. Therefore I'am using NGINX in front of WSGI. There is no problem to configure SSL in NGINX, but for WSGI it is.

Because I have port-forwarding from 80 to 443, the user receives an:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://example.com/static/css/bootstrap-3.3.5.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

How can I enable SSL for WSGI?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [I can not connect to https waitress wsgi server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19462959/) i found the solution. Just add "url_scheme = https" to your production.ini / development.ini.